# How to remove duplicated row by timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a products table with the following schema:

```
id  createdOn, updatedOn, stock, status
```

`createdOn` & `updatedOn` are `TimeStamp`.

`createdOn` is the paratition field.

Say this is the data I have now:

```
id  createdOn,                    updatedOn,                stock, status
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10    5
2   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  5     12
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
```

I have a `ETL` that append new rows to this table. when the ETL is finished I can have a situation where the same `id` has more than 1 row.

For example:

```
id  createdOn,                    updatedOn,                stock, status
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10    5
2   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  5     12
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-15 10:00:00.000000  7     5
```

I want to have a query which will run over the table and make sure that each id has only 1 row - the row with the `MAX(updatedOn)` should stay. There can be more than 1 row for the `MAX(updatedOn)` per id - in that case it's guarantee that they are identical, because if they weren't than the `updatedOn` field would have been modified.

After ruuning the query the table will look like:

```
id  createdOn,                    updatedOn,                stock, status
2   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  5     12
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-15 10:00:00.000000  7     5
```

How can I write a query that efficiently perform this?

I know it should be something like:

```
DELETE FROM products
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM products
    GROUP BY id
)
```

However this won't work... I don't have auto-increment field to distinguish the rows.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

use `row_number` function

```
DELETE FROM products
WHERE STRUCT(id,createdOn,stock) IN (
        select id,createdOn,stock from
        (SELECT id,createdOn,stock,
          ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn,stock,updatedOn order by id) as rn from products
                  ) t where rn>1
         )
```

Another way you can follow rather delete you can replace your table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE products AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY createdOn,stock,updatedOn order by id) rn
  FROM products
) 
WHERE rn> 1
```

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "row_number" at [6:15]

Comment: @Programmer120 see now

Comment: @Pentium10 why do I need the  SELECT * ? This brings unnecessary columns.. This costs money in BigQuery.  Also shouldn't the partition be `By id order by updatedOn`  ?

Comment: the partition syntax you recommend is better, select * is not a problem until you don't return anything, on delete syntax there is no problem for costs.

Comment: @Pentium10 but you do return... the query is executed fully and only then the delete is executed.

Comment: @Pentium10 The query runs with select. It doesn't run with DELETE it says Unexpected "(" at [2:13]

Comment: Error: Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [5:8]

Comment: @Programmer120 could you please check once more

Comment: can you explain the struct? I have 89 columns I didn't post all of them here as it was irrelevant for the question.

Comment: @Programmer120 way of parsing sub-query in big-query and btw i put in answer another way i think it is more easy for your case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180154/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-programmer120).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you just create a new table:

```
create table correct_table as
    select distinct id, createdOn, updatedOn
    from etl_table;
```

BigQuery's strength is processing the data.  I try to find other solutions (such as copying tables) when updates or deletes seem to be needed.

You may want to re-think your processing.  Just have the ETL load a table with the new rows.  Then use BigQuery to insert the new rows that don't already exist.  In other words, inserting the rows and then deleting them is not the way to go.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work. The "old table" can contain rows that are not in the ETL that I'm running.  What I'm actually trying to do is some sort of UPSERT solution. I can create a WIP table and work on it and when finish perforing WRITE_TRUNCATE from it to the production table but still either way you need to perform delete or updates.. nothing was saved.

Comment: @Programmer120 . . . You don't need to perform `delete`s or `update`s, or at least I haven't needed to yet on the systems I implement in BigQuery.  But that is not the question you asked here.  I was just offering that as a solution beyond the scope of the question.  The answer I provided is to create a new table rather than deleting from the old one (using `select distinct`, but if you have other columns not mentioned in the question, you might need slightly different logic).

Comment: I have 98 columns with nesting. I understand you took it out of scope.. that's ok I just didn't understand your logic. You suggested to run the ETL and then copy from the old table only the id's that does not exist. That still requires to pass row by row. keep in mind that my partition is on the createdate which doesn't participate here.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gordon Linoff is right, BigQuery use case is not to manipulate data and update already existing rows all the time. [It's to fill it enormously and then analyze that data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

Anyway, this query would return just the rows you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, createdOn,  updatedOn,  stock,  status
FROM `project.dataset.maxtimestamp` AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id AS i2, MAX(updatedOn) AS up
FROM `project.dataset.maxtimestamp`
GROUP BY id) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.i2 AND t1.updatedOn = t2.up
```

As well as this one that you already found:

```
SELECT id,  createdOn,  updatedOn,  stock,  status
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id ORDER BY updatedOn desc) AS rn
       FROM `training-wave-12-vmarin.asdf.duplicated_timestamp` AS t2)
WHERE rn>1
```

Anyway, not sure about how optimized it is...