# What is the proper syntax for delete query with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query where the ID is not UNIQUE:

```
delete
      ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id  order by updatedOn) as rn , id FROM `a.tab` ) as t
    WHERE t.rn> 1;
```

The inner select return the result but the delete fails with:

> Error: Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [2:7]

What is the syntax problem here?

Comment: Which table are you deleting from?

Comment: Here is the [online documentation of DELETE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement).

Comment: @dustytrash `a.tab`  I'm querying it for multiple appearances of the same id and I want to remove the oldest records by updatedOn.

Comment: @UweKeim I'm aware of the docs. There is no answer for my question in the docs

Comment: Just copy the rows you want into a new table.  That is usually the most efficient approach in BigQuery.

Comment: Also, in your use case it should be "ORDER BY updateOn DESC", if not u'll delete the new ones...

Answer (score 1):

Unlike SQL Server, and a few other databases, Big Query does not allow deleting directly from a CTE.  But, we can specify your target table, and then use the row number in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable AS t1
WHERE (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id ORDER BY updatedOn)
       FROM yourTable AS t2
       WHERE t1.id = t2.id) > 1;
```

The idea here is to correlate the row number value to each row in the delete statement using the `id`, which is presumably a primary key.

Comment: Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: The logic for what i'm trying to do is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352520/how-to-remove-duplicated-row-by-timestamp-in-bigquery

Comment: Please try my query and it if fails, then give feedback.

Comment: It fails.. I wrote the error: Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: Are you using standard or legacy?  Also, did you run my _exact_ query, or did you copy it and then change stuff?  The error message implies more than one table when my answer does not.

Comment: I'm using SQL standard.

Comment: `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables` ... this never happens in the query I gave you.

Comment: mmm you are ware that in my case I'm querying and deleting from the same table?

Comment: I think the problem is because that id is not unique. The SELECT selects the rows to kept, but then there are also duplicated rows, so when you do "t1.id = t2.id" there are multiple matches and that's not possible.

Comment: @Temu Actually what you are describing should not be possible because no two `id` values, by definition, can have the same `ROW_NUMBER` value.

Comment: Well, these are not unique IDs, Tim. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352520/how-to-remove-duplicated-row-by-timestamp-in-bigquery/53140337#53140337)

Comment: The OP failed to give sample data in this question.  My answer was reasonable in the absence of any sample data.

Comment: Your answer is totally reasonable and cool, dude. But it doesn't work for this use case. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use query as ::
delete from t 
    From  ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id  order by updatedOn) as rn , id FROM `a.tab` ) as t
    WHERE t.rn> 1;

Hope this works